# Lightbox image is displayed behind the modal (bootstrap) but I want it to be displayed over the modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, lightbox2

Lightbox (Lokesh dhakar lightbox2) image is displayed behind the modal (bootstrap) whe clicked on the image link but I want it to be displayed over the modal. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of the modal is higher than the Lightbox z-index. If you increase the z-index Lightbox you will have image over the modal.

Example Z-index in Lightbox:

```
.lightbox{
   z-index: 100000;
}
```